resize2fs No such file or directory while opening
I'm having a simple trouble updating my block storage using resize2fs.
The error message sounds quite simple and straight forward, but I have no clue to solve this problem.
$ kubectl exec -it es-prod-es-default-0 -n namespace -- /bin/bash
$ df -hT
elasticsearch@es-prod-es-default-0:~$ df -hT
Filesystem     Type     Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
overlay        overlay  100G   83G   18G  83% /
tmpfs          tmpfs     64M     0   64M   0% /dev
tmpfs          tmpfs    3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/vda1      xfs      100G   83G   18G  83% /tmp
shm            tmpfs     64M     0   64M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs          tmpfs    2.0G  8.0K  2.0G   1% /mnt/elastic-internal/pod-mounted-users
tmpfs          tmpfs    2.0G  4.0K  2.0G   1% /mnt/elastic-internal/elasticsearch-config
tmpfs          tmpfs    2.0G  4.0K  2.0G   1% /mnt/elastic-internal/downward-api
tmpfs          tmpfs    2.0G   32K  2.0G   1% /mnt/elastic-internal/xpack-file-realm
/dev/vdb       ext4     147G  133G   14G  91% /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
tmpfs          tmpfs    2.0G  4.0K  2.0G   1% /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/transport-remote-certs
tmpfs          tmpfs    2.0G  4.0K  2.0G   1% /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/operator
tmpfs          tmpfs    2.0G   12K  2.0G   1% /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/http-certs
tmpfs          tmpfs    2.0G   12K  2.0G   1% /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/transport-certs
tmpfs          tmpfs    3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /proc/acpi
tmpfs          tmpfs    3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /proc/scsi
tmpfs          tmpfs    3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/firmware

$ resize2fs /dev/vdb
resize2fs 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
open: No such file or directory while opening /dev/vdb

Thanks for your help in advance!

The error ”No such file or directory while opening /dev/vdb” means ‘dev/vdb’ does not exist. So check the current availability of the block device in the system by using below command  fdisk-1. (fdisk tries to update the kernel after it has written the partition table. However this will fail if the disk is in use). You can also run the lsblk command to check which partition needs to be extended.
Make sure you have proper permissions to manage block devices check by using below command
sudo growpart /dev/vdb

 sudo resize2fs /dev/vdb.
Run df -h now it shows more available space and refer to this document also.
